# How to extract uncommon case insensitive text from two files?

Tags: command-line, 16.04, text-processing

I am trying to extract uncommon text from the file and I have tried this:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$0]++; next} !a[$0]' 1.txt 2.txt
http://PQR.com
http://example.com
```

Here are the input files:

```
File: 1.txt
http://google.com
http://GOOGLE.com
http://example1.com
http://seperate.com
http://pqr.com
File: 2.txt
http://PQR.com
http://example.com
http://google.com
```

As you can see, `http://pqr.com` is available in file `1.txt` and `http://PQR.com` in `2.txt`. and the result display `http://PQR.com`, which is common in both file. Hence, how I can show only the uncommon text (not depending upon the cases of the text)?

Comment: text, meaning lines? if so, how big are the files?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Yes text refer to a single line of a file. File size say 1.txt is 2 GB and 2.txt is 5GB

Comment: By "uncommon", do you mean the union of the set differences "(A ∖ B) ∪ (B ∖ A)"?

Comment: @DavidFoerster No it is like only A\B or B\A. No union of two.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're already using `awk`, use `tolower` to lowercase the lines:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[tolower($0)]++; next} !a[tolower($0)]' foo bar
```

However, this only prints lines in `bar` which were not in `foo`.

Compare with:

```
$ sort -f bar foo | uniq -iu
http://example.com
http://example1.com
http://seperate.com
```

With `awk`, you also need to print every line which was seen only once:

```
$ awk '{a[tolower($0)]++} END {for (i in a) if (a[i] == 1) print i}' foo bar
http://seperate.com
http://example.com
http://example1.com
```

Comment: Thank you muru. Even though the command is slow. It worked.

Comment: Can I use sort command to get uncommmon values from a single file? As I see the sort command you have mentioned gives uncommon from both the files, which good one. but can I get from one file only as awk works?

Comment: `sort -f foo | uniq -u`?

Comment: no not like that. The values which are present in `foo` and `bar` are not what I want. I want simply `foo` - `bar`.

Comment: @JafferWilson then use your original command with `tolower`, but reverse the order of files.

Answer (score 4):

This is a pretty simple job for `grep`:

```
grep -viFf file2.txt file1.txt
```

- `-v` shows the lines that do not match
- `-i` enables case-insensitivity
- `-F` makes patterns literal
- `-f file1.txt` reads patterns to match from `file1.txt`, line by line

**Example:**

```
% cat file1.txt 
http://google.com
http://GOOGLE.com
http://example1.com
http://seperate.com
http://pqr.com

% cat file2.txt 
http://PQR.com
http://example.com
http://google.com

% grep -viFf file2.txt file1.txt
http://example1.com
http://seperate.com
```

Comment: Your command showed `aims@aims:~/Downloads/Uncommon1$ grep -viFf 2.txt 1.txt > output.txt
grep: memory exhausted
`

Comment: Look at the file size, grep is choking in file sizes like this.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a Python solution using an efficient set implementation for nice *O*(*n*+*m*) performance (with *n* and *m* being the sizes of the two input files).

### Code

```python
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1]) as A_file:
    A = frozenset(map(str.casefold, map(str.rstrip, A_file)))

with open(sys.argv[2]) as B_file:
    B = map(str.rstrip, B_file))
    B_minus_A = filter(lambda s: s.casefold() not in A, B)
    print(*B_minus_A, sep='\n')
```

### Usage example

```
python3 casefold-difference.py 1.txt 2.txt
```

### Explanation

- The program uses [`casefold`](//docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) for string comparison yet returns the lines as they appear in `2.txt`. Case folding is the recommended way to do case-insensitive comparison of natural language. If that's not what you want (since URLs aren't actually natural language) you may replace it with `lower`.
- If `2.txt` has a huge amount of lines (that don't appear in `1.txt`) the creation of the variadic argument list in the last statement may consume quite a lot of memory and you may be better off to replace it with a loop like this:

  ```python
  for item in B_minus_A:
      print(item)
  ```